# Most Frequently updated table(s) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL keep statistics regarding the update/insert usage of particular tables/databases in the performance_schema or information_schema?

Is there a simple way to access this data per table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does in the binary log. See the [documentation page on MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/binary-log.html) for more information, it even has a useful script at the bottom you can modify to show information on a per table basis.